# Why the array bounds index can also be used?

Tags: c, arrays, char, bounds

```
char str2[13];
str2[13] = '\0';
```

Look at the above example, the maximum legal index of `str2` is 12, but in this example 13, `str2[13] can also work`.
Here's the code snippet:

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main(){
    char *str1 = "we are happy!";
    char str2[13];
    str2[13] = '\0';
    printf("Before: %s\n", str2);
    char *p = str2;
    while( *str1!='\0' )
        *p++ = *str1++;
    printf("After: %s\n", str2);
}
```

How? Can anyone explain this?

Comment: Most of the time in C, the answer to "why can I do this thing I thought wasn't allowed" is that it just didn't happen to blow up in your face *this time*.

Comment: In Turbo C, This code will work. But that's wrong way of defining . str2[13] = '\0'; array index starts with 0 to 12 only.

Comment: In gcc 4.6.3, it can work. Since this is Undefined behavior, it may crashing the program or not crashing the program. What happening depends on whether overwriting on stack.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Accessing an index out of bounds invokes **undefined behavior**. This means it may do anything including crashing your program or **not** crashing your program. Also it is possible that the code above crashes sometime and works other times. That is why it is called **undefined behavior**. It is **your** responsibility never to invoke undefined behavior.

Answer (score 1):

You are accessing un-allocated memory (by going out of bound) and this invokes [**undefined behavior**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior). You may get either expected or unexpected output. Anything could happen.

Answer (score 1):

C is not a memory safe (or managed) language and allows you to access memory outside the bounds of an array. It trusts that you know what you are doing in order to maintain lightning fast performance.

Answer (score 1):

This is `str2[13] = '\0';` incorrect code. Currently it many not be give any impact. But when you work with the large system, this `str2[13] = '\0';` boundary crossing will create problem.

Answer (score 0):

You are writing to memory that does not belong to the array. Not recommended.

Comment: "Not recommended." as in "It is not recommended to murder your neighbour"? What the OP does is undefined behaviour - which is "strictly forbidden".

Comment: More like modify properties of your neighbor's house. Not recommended unless you know what you're doing.

Answer (score 0):

If it works, it works by chance. It is completely depending on how variables are organized on the stack.

If you are unlucky, your overcounting `\0`, which doesn't fit in the string any longer, overwrites something important on the stack, e. g. the return address, which would make your `main()` crash upon returning.

If you are "semi-unlucky", you overwrtie something else on the stack, such as the variable `str1`. (You could verify that with a strategic `printf("str1 = %p\n", str1);` at appropriate places), i. e. before and after doing the illegal stuff.

And if you are completely happy, you write to a place which is not important as it was left free, e. g. due to alignment issues on the stack.

Whatever counts here (I think here you are "completely happy"), you are not allowed to do it this way. Upon changing compiler, compiler options or whatever, undefined behaviour can (and eventually will) bite you.